# How to create a functional javascript search bar

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a functional search bar for a website that checks to see if something is true or not, it is not numbers that I am looking for all I'm trying to do is enter a collage course and see if it is true or not, I have all of the courses in an array and yes there is a lot of them like 1500 or so in one array, I just can't figure out how to create something that basically says yes or not to it being likely to transfer to another college, I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense at all but it's something that I have to get done pretty soon, thank you.

[This is  the code right here in my codepen](https://codepen.io/nephera-branch/pen/oNZKRBj?editors=1011)

```
var courses = true;
var keys=document.getElementById('key');
var but=document.getElementById('sb');

function searchFun() {
 if(courses == true) {
 document.write(keys.value + " Is Likely");
 } if(courses == false) {
document.write(keys.value + " Is Unlikely");
 }
 }
but.addEventListener('click', searchFun);
```

Comment: are you looking to search the array for whats in the box? your question is unclear. *something is true or not*, what? *enter a collage course and see if it is true or not*, your array is full of strings there are no boolean values. *likely to transfer to another college*?

Comment: Yes I am trying to search for what is in the array, basically you enter a college course into the search bar and when you hit submit I want it to say if that course is likely to transfer to another college, that's why there are so many college courses in my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not it what you searched for?
Note, that for demonstration  I took only a few elements of your original courses array.

```js
var courses = ["Composition I", "Rhetoric I", "College Writing I", "College Composition I","Principles of Composition", "Rhetoric and Composition I", "Composition II", "Rhetoric II,College Writing II", "College Composition II", "Forms of Composition", "Rhetoric and Composition II", "Human Communication", "Public Speaking", "Fundamentals of Speech Communication"]

var courseInput = document.getElementById('key');
var but=document.getElementById('sb');

function searchFun() {
  if(courses.includes(courseInput.value)) { 
    document.write(`${courseInput.value} is Likely`);
  }else{
    document.write(`${courseInput.value} is Unlikely`);
  }
}

but.addEventListener('click', searchFun);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  
</head>
  <body>
    <center>
      search Box <input type="course" id="key">
      <button id="sb">search</button>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```